# How to do currency formatting in HandleBar in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, handlebars.java

Does handlebar support currency formatting? Something like below for instance?

```
IDR{{amount}}
SGD{{amount}}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to use.

```
 {{numberFormat number ["format"] [locale=default]}}
```

this is the general use. Format parameters are used as integers, percentages, currency, or the default formatter.

for currency

```
{{numberFormat 1.638 "currency"}} 

Output: $1.63
```

for different currency

```
{{numberFormat 1.638 "currency" "de_DE"}}
Output: 1,63 €
```

if you want to use this format for percent

```
{{numberFormat .46 "percent"}}
Output: 46%
```

Comment: This sounds very nice. BUT: It is not plain handlebars.js!

Something similar can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/DennyLoko/6sR87/

Answer (score 0):

Handlebar.java supports currency formatting for numerical values only.

So, if your data looks like... { "amount" : 32 }
...you're fine using selahaddin aksu's answer.

However, if your 'number' is actually a string value... { "amount" : "32" }
...you will need to use an additional helper to convert the string to a number datatype first, otherwise your output will return the string value of "currency" instead of a formatted number.

You can use this custom helper...

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("toNum", function (n) {
    return parseFloat(n) || +n;
});
```

...like this...

```
1: "amount": 27.5,
2: "amount": "72.3",
3: "amount": -32,
4: "amount": "-23"

{{numberFormat (toNum amount1) "currency"}}

OUTPUT -
1: $27.50
2: $72.30
3: -$32.00
4: -$23.00
```